# I want to create a Confusion Matrix

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, confusion-matrix

**The Code for the model architecture**

```
#CNN Based Model in Keras

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=(224,224,3)))
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(128,(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
```

**Prediction**

```
path = "/content/CovidDataSet/Val/Covid/0a7faa2a.jpg"
img = image.load_img(path, target_size=(224,224))

img = image.img_to_array(img)/255
img = np.array([img])
img.shape

(model.predict(img) > 0.5).astype("int32")
```

Now I want to create a confusion matrix and have no idea what to code since I am a beginner and will be grateful if anyone can provide

Answer (score 0):

You can get the confusion matrix with this function and change the variables that you are using wrt:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import itertools

def plot_confusion_matrix(cm, classes,
                          normalize=False,
                          title='Confusion matrix',
                          cmap=plt.cm.Blues):

    if normalize:
        cm = cm.astype('float') / cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
        print("Normalized confusion matrix")
    else:
        print('Confusion matrix, without normalization')

    print(cm)

    plt.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.colorbar()
    tick_marks = np.arange(len(classes))
    plt.xticks(tick_marks, classes, rotation=45)
    plt.yticks(tick_marks, classes)

    fmt = '.2f' if normalize else 'd'
    thresh = cm.max() / 2.
    for i, j in itertools.product(range(cm.shape[0]), range(cm.shape[1])):
        plt.text(j, i, format(cm[i, j], fmt),
               horizontalalignment="center",
               color="white" if cm[i, j] > thresh else "black")

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.ylabel('True label')
    plt.xlabel('Predicted label')
    plt.show()


p_test = model.predict(X_test).argmax(axis=1)
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, p_test)
plot_confusion_matrix(cm, list(range(10)))
```

Comment: which vairables to create I didnt create any variables hence i changed the x_test and y_test to the img but getting an error Classification metrics can't handle a mix of unknown and binary targets

Comment: When i Created X_test [] and y_test [] it gave me this error
KeyError: 'pop from an empty set'